# Send SMS without user interaction in Android

Tags: android

Here is my code:

SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, smsMessage, null, null);

Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to send an SMS without prompting user.

Comment: is your current code not working ro what?

Comment: Yes. the above code Prompting user a dialogbox with two options (Cancel(Counting on it) & Send). If user not respond to this dialog then by default it is canceling that dialog and not sending sms